# Can't install Heroku CLI on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, heroku-cli

I've just started using my RP3 as my development box, and got everything working fine: Python 3.6, created venv's, installed posgresql, working with Django. All is fine. Except that, if I want to work with Heroku, their CLI (former Toolbelt) won't install, stating the package doesn't exist.

**What I did:**

Their [official site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#debian-ubuntu) states that we should run a script:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Which basically seems to include heroku on the sources for `apt-get`, update it (`apt-get update`) and then install by running `apt-get install heroku`. Full output is here:

```
$ sudo wget -qO- https://cli-    assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
+ SUDO=
+ id -u
+ [ 1000 != 0 ]
+ SUDO=sudo
+ echo This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
+ echo You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
+ sudo -k
+ sudo sh
+ dpkg -s apt-transport-https
+ echo deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./
+ dpkg -s heroku-toolbelt
+ true
+ apt-key add -
+ wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key
OK
+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]
Hit https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ InRelease
Hit https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Packages
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages [9,533 kB]
Get:3 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB [364 B]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Get:4 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en [361 B]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Get:5 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB [364 B]
Get:6 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en [361 B]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Get:7 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB [364 B]
Get:8 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en [361 B]
Get:9 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB [364 B]
Get:10 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en [361 B]
Get:11 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB [364 B]
Ign https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_GB
Get:12 https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en [361 B]
Ign https://cli-assets.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
Get:13 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages [43.3     kB]
Get:14 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages [84.2     kB]
Get:15 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages [1,356 B]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
Fetched 9,677 kB in 21s (450 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
+ apt-get install -y heroku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku
```

Installing what they call the ["Standalone" program](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone) also doesn't seem it would work, since there are builds for x86 and x64 only, not ARM, which is the RPI's architecture.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this? I found other questions like this online, but no answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the standalone heroku toolbelt for linux arm like it is described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#set-up (select "Download standalone version of the Heroku CLI")

```sh
# Run this from your terminal.
# Replace OS with one of “linux”, “darwin”, “windows”, “freebsd”, “openbsd”
# Replace ARCH with one of “amd64”, “386” or “arm”
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
# ensure that /usr/local/bin is in the PATH environment variable
```

I have it running on my RP3 with raspbian jessie

```sh
$ heroku --version
heroku-cli/5.7.1-c574890 (linux-arm) go1.7.5
```

Comment: Great, @Cyrus, thanks! Luckily you ran into outdated instructions that seem to work better than the "[official CLI site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone)", which states that only x86 or x64 are available. I confirm I could install with these instructions, and a very old version (5.7.1) gets installed as you have shown. Thankfully, the CLI has a self-updating feature that kick in after a few commands and now I have:
`$ heroku --version`
`heroku-cli/6.12.17-aa05cb0 (linux-arm) node-v8.1.4`

Comment: Glad that it worked for you as well! And you're right. My installation also updated itself to 6.12.17 by itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Heroku support, there's no official support at this time (July 2017) with snap being an option in the future. They claim some people manage to do it with npm, which I also tried without success.

Their response:

> Hey Marcelo,
>
> We're currently working on a cross-platform install method for the CLI with snap. I can let you know here when it's publicly available. Some folks have got the CLI to install on arm via npm but we don't officially support it. Snap should be a great solution for arm users when it's ready (snap will also show up [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) when public).
>
> Thanks for reaching out!